# Really need some help styling html

Tags: html, styling

I can't seem to figure out why my style attributes aren't having an effect on my `div`s. The only one that seems to work is the `body` tag.

It's for a course I'm currently doing. I feel like I've tried everything but can't get it to work. I'm pretty sure it's something minor that I'm missing but it is really frustrating me.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

PageBanner {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  width: 50px;
}

NavBar {
  background: #FD0C10;
}

Header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

Subheading {
  text-align: center;
}

Content {}

Footer {}
```

```html
body>
<div wrapper="Mainwrapper">

  <div class="PageBanner"><img src="../images/banner.jpg" alt="PageBanner"></div>

  <div class="Navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>

      </li>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="Header">
    <h1>The Club Site</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="SubHeading">
    <h2>Members Prices</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="Content">

  </div>

  <div class="Footer">

  </div>

</div>
<!--Mainwrapper-->

</body>
```

Comment: if you are using a class you should either use in `<style>`  which tag it is relevant to, or need the dot to specify it is a class: like instead of `Content {...}` you should either do `div.Content {...}` or `.Content {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Have the css class definition like `.PageBanner` which will work like you expected `PageBanner` refers to a tag with name `PageBanner`. And `#PageBanner` refers to an element which has id `PageBanner`

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  background: color: red;
}

.PageBanner {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  width: 50px;
  background:red;
}

.NavBar {
  background: #FD0C10;
}

.Header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Subheading {
  text-align: center;
}

.Content {}

.Footer {}
```

```html
<div wrapper="Mainwrapper">

  <div class="PageBanner"><img src="../images/banner.jpg" alt="PageBanner">
  </div>

  <div class="Navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>

      </li>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="Header">
    <h1>The Club Site</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="SubHeading">
    <h2>Members Prices</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="Content">

  </div>

  <div class="Footer">

  </div>

</div>
<!--Mainwrapper-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a **CSS Selector**
to make your style work.

```
Selector     Example                 Example description
.class       .Header                Selects all elements with class="Header" 
                                    <div class="Header">

#id          #firstname             Selects the element with id="firstname"
                                    <input id="firstname">
```

Please do read this link for more info about CSS Selector Reference.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been given. But make sure to pay close attention to how you write your CSS because this case you were trying to define a class but was missing the dot `.class` but also you can do ids which are defined `#class`. You had a good approach you were just missing the signifying selector.